# Player incline() function fail with TiledSprite

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, sprite, game-physics

Hi I'm developing a game by using andengine.I have a player in my game created with TiledSprite.Also there box2d physic engine.Here is the porblem: Player is moving ahead.But a while later there is a wall on his top and if he wanna continue to go ahead, he has to incline.Incline method just make "player.setCurrentTileIndex(12);". So player image is getting small(incline position).Till here everything is right.But playerBody isn't getting small.That's why he still can't pass the wall by inclining.How can I solve it?
You can understand the problem with photos better:
In this picture, he can't go in there:
http://t1310.hizliresim.com/1g/j/tmpyd.png
In this picture, he can go in there but he can't:
http://j1310.hizliresim.com/1g/j/tmpz2.png

Answer (score 0):

I searched this stutation and found this: destroy the fixture and create new one. But I need this solution with code examples. I couldn't get it well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new body for it everytime.